# Is there a way to attach ChromeDriver to a web page opened manually?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a bot in python which help me login into my account everyday and download some sort of data. But the problem is when I want to login with chromedriver the webpage asks to enter security code. because of this I decided to login manually and only automate the download procedure.

But I don't know if chromedriver can be attached to an already manually opened webpage? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this answer 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/145411

As chrome driver load default profile it causes problem while logging in many sites so you can change the default profile with your own profile which you used to work and open daily

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

I hope this will resolve you problem with security code as many website and system ask for security because chrome driver is easily identifiable by the website so they want you to perform the security check.

You can't even log in to google account using a web chrome driver but if you change profile it can be possible.

Comment: you can now close this thread and approve this as an answer. & I'm glad